# Почему спирт - нашатырный?

Tags: этимология

Подскажите, пожалуйста, название спирта "нашатырный" - откуда оно пошло? Почему он так называется?
Спасибо

Comment: Нашатырь - носодер.

Answer (score 2):

Нос дерет --нушадир --не трудно догадаться, откуда этимология. Действие совпадает с названием. Носадер, горладер-неспроста это. Остальное огрехи толмачества. Это и в тюркских есть--ношотур, naşatır салааммонит- sel ammoniac--перевод-соль аммиачная-Хлорид аммония (хлористый аммоний, техническое название — нашаты́рь) NH4Cl — соль аммония, белый кристаллический слегка гигроскопичный порошок без запаха. Не следует путать с нашатырным спиртом — водным раствором аммиака. Аммиа́к — NH3, нитрид водорода, при нормальных условиях — бесцветный газ с резким характерным запахом (запах нашатырного спирта).
это вовсе не спирт. Название идет от латинского spirit - дух.
Хлорид аммония+щелочь, выделяется аммиак.
Более конкретно - аммиак выделяется при гниении испражнений(там имеется соль аммония), при непосредственном нагревании хлорида аммония с выделением еще и соляной кислоты,а нагрев само собой при гниении.

Именно этим и пользовались,нагревом и шелочной реакцией с потовыми выделениями, давая нюхать кристаллы, нагревая их.

Что касается истории - темный лес, 
Доходит до того, что от незнания химии, пишут ерунду откровенную, кто во что горазд..
«Римляне называли залежи нашатырного спирта(газа?), который они собирали возле Храма Амуна (от греческого Ἄμμων Аммон) в древней Ливии, «sal ammoniacus» (соль Амуна) из-за близости к соседнему храму. Соли нашатырного спирта были известны с Плиния, хотя не известно, идентичен ли термин более современному определению «sal-ammoniac» (нашатырный спирт).»

Цель собирания непонятна. Использование в больших масштабах не ясно.
В природе нашатырь не образует больших скоплений. Он встречается в виде небольших налетов и корочек, часто вместе с серой, около вулканов, в пещерах и трещинах земной коры.
В форме хлорида аммония (nushadir) нашатырный спирт имел важное значение для мусульманских алхимиков уже в VIII столетии, впервые его упоминает арабский химик Джабир ибн Хайян и европейским алхимикам с XIII века, когда его упомянул Альберт Великий. Его также использовали средневековые красильщики в форме сброженной мочи для изменения цвета растительных красителей. В XV веке Василий Валентин доказал, что нашатырный спирт можно получить посредством действия щелочи на хлорид аммония. Позднее, когда хлорид аммония получали посредством дистилляции копыт и рогов волов и нейтрализации полученного карбоната с соляной кислотой, нашатырный спирт называли «духом оленьего рога». spirit cervi cornibus

Источник:http://www.nazdor.ru/topics/improvement/preparations/current/469050/

Не иначе арабы в 8 веке владели русским языком, а это не исключено, либо это заимствование, опять проблемы у официальной истории..

Answer (score 1):

Нашатырь, en: Salmiak. Назв. от арабск. нушадир - вдыхать, нюхать. Синонимы: хлорид аммония, сальмиак, саламониак, салааммонит (хим.).
http://wiki.web.ru/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C

Источник, конечно, не абсолютно авторитетный, но вполне правдоподобно.

Answer (score 0):

Еще со школьных уроков химии мне казалось, что ***"нашатырь"*** - это просто слегка видоизмененное прочтение формулы ***"ЭнАшТри"*** (NH₃), и никакого дополнительного происхождения этого слова искать не нужно.
Впрочем, вполне возможно, что в традициях кого-то языка NH₃ читается еще ближе к варианту ***"НаШаТырь"***, и в русский язык это слово пришло именно из языка с таким прочтением.